# 18bit Serdes - Xilinx Spartan6

Tags: fpga, xilinx, serial-bus, spartan-6

In a project with FPGA stereo vision I use two MT9V032 cameras. The cameras are connected as in the application example in the data sheet.

[image: Stereo vision topology]

In stereo output mode the data length is 18bits long. There is one start bit and one stop bit. So there are 8 bits for each pixel of master and slave camera.

[image: Data format stereo vision]

In Application Note XAPP1064 I read that maximum bitlength of 16bits is possible for Spartan 6 Deserialization. Is there a trick to support higher deserialization factors?

As I do not need the start and stop bit, is there a solution to deserialize only the bits between start and stop bit?

Comment: One possible solution which came into my mind is:


The clock for the camera is generated by the FPGA. The clock in the FPGA is 2* SYS_CLOCK of the camera. The clock must be divided by 2 before output to camera.


The clock source of the ISERDES2 blocks is the internal clock. Two cascaded ISERDES2 blocks are used to decode 5 + 4 bits. So I get 9bits for one internal clock. With the second clock, I get another 9bits.

Comment: 9bit serdes factors are not possible

Comment: If 9bit is not possible in each block, you do 9bit serdes to get a half width data bus, and then do 2:1 deserializing within the FPGA fabric now that the data is at a much slower rate.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to use a gearbox to re-pack the bits from whatever deserializer width makes the most sense. Altera has some example gearboxes in their cookbook, as well as some design techniques.